# How do I sum multiple "IF" statements without "Sumifs"

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have to put together a weekly reporting system in Excel. I need to report on the month to dale sales results and the completed week (Fri-Thu). This is collected from multiple sales agents in sales documents stored in Sharepoint.

For this, I've used "SUMIFS" to collect the data, the following way:

```
=SUMIFS('SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[One off],'SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date],">="&B7,'SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date],"<="&C7)
```

(B7 is a cell reference which determines the start date of the week, with C7 being the end of the week)

The trouble with SUMIFS, as well as SUMIF, COUNTBLANK, COUNTIF and COUNTIFS, is that they don't work when the sourcing document is closed. Microsoft has a workaround here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/260415?wa=wsignin1.0

I can't seem to figure out how to adapt the workaround methodology recommended to apply not just to a simple IF statement, but to multiples. I assume I would need to use an "AND" statement, but I keep getting errors when I'm trying.

I have about half a dozen different calculations to make, but I am pretty confident if I can solve this one, the others should start to gel a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=SUM(IF('SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date]>=B7,IF('SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date]<=C7,'SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[One off])))`

Entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Non-Array formula equivalent:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--('SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date]>=B7),--('SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[Date]<=C7),'SHAREPOINTREF/FILE.xlsm'!SalesResults[One off])`

But both seems to return `#REF!` when source WB is closed even though the link provided in the question claims otherwise.

**Edit1:**

After more digging, above will work but you need to use a *Normal Range* and not a *Table Range*.
The only problem is, you loose the advantage of *Table's Dynamic Data Range*.
So something like this will work even if the source is closed:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--('SHAREPOINTREF/[FILE.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$11>=B7),--('SHAREPOINTREF/[FILE.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$11<=C7),'SHAREPOINTREF/[FILE.xlsm]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$11)`

Comment: I tried this (nearly verbatim, except substituting the actual file paths in) and it's calculating just fine. But it's still giving me `#REF!` when I close the document.

Comment: @LincM Yeah. I saw it too. It is indeed returning that contrary to what the link you posted say. I tested `SUMIFS` too and the same `#REF!` error occurs.

Comment: I'll try this shortly and will let you know. The logic of the argument above seems sound, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thanks! Now to reverse engineer this to take over the galaxy.

Comment: Can this be used to simulate `COUNTA`?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to use **array formulas**. Those are a special type of formula that, when typed, must be activated by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter in the formula bar. Such a function works by applying a function that would normally accept a single cell (such as IF() ) to a range. You will need to wrap the result in an aggregating formula such as SUM() or COUNT(). Here's an example:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$10="Apple", $B$1:$B$10, 0))
```

This formula would check each cell from A1 to A10 and compare it to "Apple", if it is true it will return the corresponding row from $B$1:$B$10. The result would be an array of values of column B where column A is "Apples" with zeros where it is not. The surrounding SUM() aggregates the array and gives the equivalent of SUMIF().

As I mentioned, you would need to enter Ctrl + Shift + Enter after typing the formula for it to work as an array formula. Otherwise, it will work as a regular formula.

Comment: I have tried this, even with the array, but I'm still getting the dreaded `#REF!` every time.

Is it possible that even with Arrays and nested arguments instead of simpler, less recognised functions, that it will have difficulty sourcing this information?